# dificuldade em extrair o conteudo de um ficheiro que esta numa pasta

Tags: python-3.x, string, tkinter

Boa tarde,
Eu estou utilizando a biblioteca textract para extrair conteudo dentro de uma pasta e para isso eu estou a utilizar um função que insere o inicio do diretorio('./livro') e a extensão do ficheiro('.pdf') o problema e que mesmo que o ficheiro exista ele diz que não encontra o ficheiro, este código faz parte de um projeto maior e foi quando adicionei esta parte que deixou de funcionar, eu acredito que seja um problema de strings porem não sei identificar o problema

```
import textract

def imprimir(nome):
        inicio="./livro/"
        fim=".pdf"
        ficheiro = inicio+nome+fim
        conteudo=textract.process(ficheiro)
        print(conteudo.decode('utf-8'))


array=['instrucoes']
imprimir(array[0])
```

Comment: Provavelmente ele não está encontrando o arquivo por conta do caminho relativo. Faça um teste, coloque o arquivo na pasta /tmp, por exemplo, e ao invés de colocar o caminho como `./`, que é relativo, monte um caminho absoluto como `/tmp/instrucoes.pdf`

Comment: eu tentei colocar o caminho todo desde a raiz e mesmo assim não funcionou mas eu estive a ver e será q uma raw string resolve o meu problema?

Comment: hmm eu não sei se rawstring te resolveria não. Só pra confirmar, você está num sistema linux? Se puder, copie o erro que aparece e coloque na pergunta